# Use Ram as graphics memory 5k imac

Tags: imac, memory, graphics, display, gpu

My graphics memory (4gb) is getting eaten up by my 3 or 4 apps that are open.

Is there any way to allow the graphics card to use free RAM instead of swap memory? The second the graphics card dips into swap my system gets really slow even though my memory pressure is only 10%.

Thanks!

Comment: Which apps do you run? Please add an Acitivity Monitor and an OpenGL Driver Monitor (with the correct parameters) screenshots.

Comment: How do you know your graphics card 'dips into swap'? If by swap, you mean the system SSD drive, I don't believe this is possible.